# Jenkins - Access JAVA "getProperties" from Groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to use Jenkins Groovy console to modify configuration of many jobs. I need to access a field containing additional properties passed to maven by this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin

So i figured out how to reach plugin classes:

```
for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  if (item instanceof hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet)
  {
    println("\njob $item.name ");

    rw = item.getBuildWrappers().get(hudson.plugins.release.ReleaseWrapper.class);
    if (rw == null)
    {
      println("release build not configured");
    }
    else
    {
      println("\nrelease build configured");

      println(rw.getParameterDefinitions());
      println("\n");
      println(rw.getPreBuildSteps());
      println("\n");
      for(step in rw.getPreBuildSteps()){
         println("\nPROPERTIES: " + step.getProperties())

        for(property in step.getProperties()){
          println("\nPROP: " + property)
        }
      }

    }
  } 
}
```

> PROPERTIES: [settings:jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider@307e9334,
>   class:class hudson.tasks.Maven, maven:null,
>   globalSettings:jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider@a1e5a0,
>   usePrivateRepository:false,
>   descriptor:hudson.tasks.Maven$DescriptorImpl@5481ba47,
>   injectBuildVariables:true, targets:release:prepare,
>   requiredMonitorService:NONE]

Unfortunately properties field is a list of strings describing groovy object fields instead of data I'm looking for. It should be a simple String containing additional properties for maven.

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/tasks/Maven.html#properties

It looks like Groovy has overwritten default method and field with its magic. Is there a way to reach properties anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself.

`step.properties`
reaches to Groovy properties.

`step.@properties`
reaches to the original class method.